# how to stop container trigger function

Tags: jquery

if `.hidden` is hidden after click lt(contain all whatever click on title or icon or space)  the `.hidden` will show.
then how to make only click `.icon` the `.hidden` will become hide?

now it is not work, after click `.icon` nothing happen ...  I guess because `.icon` is inside `.lt`, when click `.icon` the `.lt` will trigger click too then after hide execute `.lt` click function?

```
$('.lt').on({'click': function() {
    if(!$('.$('.hidden').is(:visible)')){
        var src="b";
        $('.icon img').attr('src', src);
        $('.hidden').show();
    }
});
$('.icon').on({'click': function() {
    if($('.$('.hidden').is(:visible)')){
        var src="a";
        $('.icon img').attr('src', src);
        $('.hidden').hide();
    }
});

<div class="lt">
    <div class="title">
    </div>
    <div class="icon">
        <img src="a">
    </div>
    <div class="hidden">
    </div>
</div>

.hidden{display:none;}
```

Comment: Thanks for remind I didn't notice should use this..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need to stop propagation of nested element's event:

```
$('.icon').on({'click': function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    //...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`.stopPropagation()` is what you need but you have issues with the code in `if` condition:

```
$('.lt').on({'click': function() {
   if(!$('.hidden').is(':visible')){  //<----change this way here
      var src="b";
      $('.icon img').attr('src', src);
      $('.hidden').show();
   }
});
```

in the above script you can check for hidden straight `if($('.hidden').is(':hidden')){`

---

Here below you have to place `.stopPropagation()` to stop the event to bubble up to its parent in the tree.

```
$('.icon').on({'click': function(e) {
   e.stopPropagation();               //<----it stops the event bubbling
   if($('.hidden').is(':visible')){   //<----this should also be changed to this
      var src="a";
      $('.icon img').attr('src', src);
      $('.hidden').hide();
   }
});
```